# React testing library with redux toolkit createAsyncThunk (How to enable Promise.race in js?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I have create createAsyncThunk to fetch the data and while dispatching thunk function, promise is being resolved with rejected action type. Does anyone have idea what's happening? It is working fine testing on browser but facing issue in unit tests and throwing error `Promise.race is not a function`

**How to enable Promise.race in js?**
[image]

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const myFunc = createAsyncThunk('returns ID', async (nameAndEmail) => {
  const response = await axios.post('/backendroute', nameAndEmail);
  return response.data.id;
});

export { myFunc };
```

Unit test code

```
import { myFunc } from './thunk';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('67087596', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const nameAndEmail = {
      name: 'John Smith',
      email: '123@123.com',
    };
    const postSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { id: '1' } });
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: function (state = '', action) {
        switch (action.type) {
          case 'returns ID/fulfilled':
            return action.payload;
          default:
            return state;
        }
      },
    });
    await store.dispatch(myFunc(nameAndEmail));
    expect(postSpy).toBeCalledWith('/backendroute', nameAndEmail);
    const state = store.getState();
    expect(state).toEqual('1');
  });
});
```

Comment: Show the unit test codes.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Please review now, Actually the issue is Promise.race() is not working in test environment